# Add HTML markup to $wpdb results in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, html, wordpress, markup

I'm pulling some data with the WPDB class in Wordpress, however - the data is being retrieved as raw data, without any markup.

How can I automatically add this markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it :)

`$text = apply___filters('the_content', $text);`

See reference at `wp-includes/formatting.php`

Answer (score 2):

Should be `$text = apply_filters( 'the_content', $text );` — one underscore.